# TypeError: history.push is not a function Why this show sometime

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand why this error not come every time sometimes the code working and sometimes not working

const dispatch = useDispatch()

```
const userDetails = useSelector(state => state.userDetails)
const { error, loading, user } = userDetails

const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin)
const { userInfo } = userLogin

const userUpdateProfile = useSelector(state => state.userUpdateProfile)
const { success } = userUpdateProfile


useEffect(() => {
        if (!userInfo) {
            **history.push**(`/login`)
        }
        else{
            if(!user || !user.name || success){
                dispatch({ type: USER_UPDATE_DETAILS_RESET })
                dispatch(getUserDetails('profile'))
            }
            else{
                setName(user.name)
                setEmail(user.email) 
            }
        }
    }, [dispatch, history, userInfo, user, success ])
```

Comment: You should use hook useHistory. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Answer (score 1):

Add `const history = useHistory();` at the top. After, you can check if its value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `history.push('/login')`.

Use this instead `history('/login')`.

For this work, the `useHistory` is no longer available as one of the react-router-dom libraries,its now `useNavigate`.

Try this

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/login')
```

Answer (score -2):

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const history = useHistory();

history.push(`/login`)